# How to update a main menu in "neoshop" theme?

Tags: magento-1.9, css, frontend, html

I would like to modify the frontend main manu in `Magento 1.9.1.0` .
I'm using the theme neoshop if this info is useful.
I've not found menu components into the `CMS -> static block nor pages` with the main menu. The menu is contained here:

```
<div class="header-maincontainer" >
   <div class="container header-primary nav" >
```

How to edit it ?

Thanks.

```
<?php $_menu = $this->getHtml('level-top') ?>
<?php if($_menu): ?>
<div class="nav-container">
    <a class="toggleMenu" title="Menu" href="#"><span>Menu</span></a>
    <ul id="nav">
        <?php
            $homeUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getHomeUrl();
            $rootUrl = str_replace("index.php/","",$homeUrl);
            $currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
            $currentUrl = explode("?",$currentUrl);
            $currentUrl = $currentUrl[0];
        ?>
        <?php if(Mage::getStoreConfig('themesettings/menu/homelink')) :?>
            <li class="home <?php if ($currentUrl === $homeUrl || $currentUrl == $rootUrl):?> active<?php endif;?>"><a class="level-top" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('')?>"><span class="homelink"><?php echo $this->__('Home') ?></span></a></li>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php echo $_menu ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give us the name of your theme, it will not really help us to help you, each theme is built differently.

I suggest two things that can help you to find your menu file.

1. Check first your menu admin config, some themes gives configuration for the menus, or implemente module with configuration.
2. Enable the path hints to find your menu file. you can find [here](http://dragonfroot.com/blog/enable-template-path-hints-for-frontend-admin-panel-in-magento/) how to enable that path hints.

Comment: I've found frontend/neoshop/default/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml but 
now how can I modify the menu

Comment: Share the content of  `topmenu.phtml`

Comment: You should have another file(s) try to enable the path hints